# Unable to verify webhooks from PayPal in Python

Tags: python, json, django, paypal, python-requests

I am trying to verify webhooks for subscriptions in paypal using django python. I am receiving the webhooks but when i send them to get verified i get this error: `{'name': 'VALIDATION_ERROR', 'message': 'Invalid request - see details', 'debug_id': 'ccc873865982', 'details': [{'field': '/', 'location': 'body', 'issue': 'MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON'}], 'links': []}`. I have checked what the status code is for the response which gives a 400 response. By looking at the [API Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/api-responses/#validation-errors) i see that invalid request + 400 response is either a validation error (which is to do with the Json format, so most likely a syntax error) or an authorization error (which says i need to change the scope). I think it is the validation error because the error points to the body.

Here is the relevant code:

```
header_params = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Language": "en_US",
}

param = {
    
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
}

cid = settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID

secret = settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET

token_i = requests.post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', auth=(cid, secret), headers=header_params, data=param).json()

token = token_i["access_token"]

bearer_token =  "Bearer x".replace('x', token)

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": bearer_token,
}

print(request.body)

webhook_event = request.body.decode("utf-8")

data = {
    
    "transmission_id": request.headers["PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-ID"],
    "transmission_time": request.headers["PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-TIME"],
    "cert_url": request.headers["PAYPAL-CERT-URL"],
    "auth_algo": request.headers["PAYPAL-AUTH-ALGO"],
    "transmission_sig": request.headers["PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-SIG"],
    "webhook_id": "3AJ143072C221060T",
    "webhook_event": webhook_event,
    
}

print(json.dumps(data))

response = requests.post('https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature', headers=headers, json=json.dumps(data)).json()

print('worked')

print(response)

if response["verification_status"] == "SUCCESS":

    print('success')
```

Here is the print of the `print(json.dumps(data))` (i removed some ids):

```
{
    "transmission_id": "id_is_here",
    "transmission_time": "2021-07-04T23:37:29Z",
    "cert_url": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/certs/CERT-360caa42-fca2a594-7a8abba8",
    "auth_algo": "auth_algo",
    "transmission_sig": "EODOx5y8kIDycYiBYcIgByiBzHyEfu1/NS2nsumOIksVuw/2vJwHj2FcuHYxIa4n/s+s25xkeqk0CXPiSuqtNUGv4pvFtpwbCVAOCU+Msn304+wBgyb7G24rwUPwrof/5jHYQxqKKX5RzxTrff4oPnisKBDUUXV4s2+KO3h2RYAhrXtwTSPt7cK5ZbGZ6SmfpYJ8qDnYFh4PIesLeflSPQ4vHQrFbgr3NiW63sZruGFJc0hTWWc8L3BhzDuUfiSrxBJLAtrqReC8R0HSV8D+Ywmdeipep54yZeJZXfbmUUGvSYbmVMsVggyzZnltyl1hP5xUd3iIi2jdNWYpLESZzA==",
    "webhook_id": "Webhook_id_is_here",
    "webhook_event": "{\"id\":\"id_here\",\"event_version\":\"1.0\",\"create_time\":\"2021-07-04T23:37:26.733Z\",\"resource_type\":\"subscription\",\"resource_version\":\"2.0\",\"event_type\":\"BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED\",\"summary\":\"Subscription created\",\"resource\":{\"start_time\":\"2021-07-04T23:37:26Z\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"create_time\":\"2021-07-04T23:37:26Z\",\"custom_id\":\"custom_id_here\",\"links\":[{\"href\":\"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/subscriptions?ba_token=BA-2UF06918UT180770Y\",\"rel\":\"approve\",\"method\":\"GET\"},{\"href\":\"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-4S15814RUE18\",\"rel\":\"edit\",\"method\":\"PATCH\"},{\"href\":\"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-4S15814RUE18\",\"rel\":\"self\",\"method\":\"GET\"}],\"id\":\"sub_id_here_\",\"plan_overridden\":false,\"plan_id\":\"P-0DA33732CG980003EMDQJ6BA\",\"status\":\"APPROVAL_PENDING\"},\"links\":[{\"href\":\"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-91E32247D9338170B-4RF07261WK370823W\",\"rel\":\"self\",\"method\":\"GET\"},{\"href\":\"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/id_here/resend\",\"rel\":\"resend\",\"method\":\"POST\"}]}"
}
```

Comment: Try to drop the `json.dumps` from the request.

Comment: @KlausD. that gives me the error `{'name': 'VALIDATION_ERROR', 'message': 'Invalid request - see details', 'debug_id': 'eb8249fc5cf0f', 'details': [{'field': '/webhook_event', 'location': 'body', 'issue': 'MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON'}], 'links': []}`

Comment: Looks like you have to `loads()` the JSON from `webhook_event`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data for the key `webhook_event` is double encoded as JSON.

You have to decode it with

```
webhook_event = json.loads(webhook_event)
```

or not encode it in the first place.